# Is there a way to make Siri play BBC radio stations?

Tags: ios, siri

Is there a way (legitimate method or an ugly hack) to enable streaming of bbc radio (four) simply by saying a voice command to Siri?

On Amazon’s Echo, saying “play radio 4” begins streaming bbc radio 4 from tunein.

Maybe there’s a clever way using Launchpad, or Workflow, or some other app?

Comment: Now that iOS 12 has come out with an updated Shortcuts app, is there a better way of doing this? Maybe with an mp3 stream of radio 4 in a Siri-compatible app?

Comment: Feel free to make this an edit to the main question so it reads like you asked this initially. Everyone will see the edit history and know that some answers came before the most recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short I don't think there is an official way at the moment.

Third-party developers like the BBC can add support for Siri to their apps now, but that is only allowed for certain use cases, and streaming radio stations doesn't seem to fit into any of them. The closest option is the CarPlay option, but that would only be useful to you while you were in the car and if your car supported CarPlay. People have asked the BBC in the past [whether they plan to support CarPlay](https://twitter.com/paulskirrow/status/779420126374424576), but the BBC didn't respond.

List of allowed use cases for SiriKit from [Apple's Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit):

- VoIP Calling - Initiate calls and search the user's call history.
- Messaging - Send messages and search the user's received messages.
- Payments - Send payments between users or pay bills.
- Lists and Notes - Create and manage notes and to-do list items.
- Visual Codes - Convey contact and payment information using Quick Response (QR) codes.
- Photos - Search for and display photos.
- Workouts - Start, end, and manage fitness routines.
- Ride Booking - Book rides and report their status.
- Car Commands - Manage vehicle door locks and get the vehicle's status.
- CarPlay - Interact with a vehicle's CarPlay system.
- Restaurant Reservations - Create and manage restaurant reservations with help from the Maps app.

Answer (score 1):

https://9to5mac.com/2017/10/17/bbc-iplayer-radio-carplay/

bbc announces CAR PLAY integration but only UK now

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Could you please add relevant info to the body of your answer? It improves legibility and ensures against link rot. I know you've got a quick summary, but it's better if you can add more.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [URLs on this page](http://steveseear.org/high-quality-bbc-radio-streams/), it is possible to create a Siri Shortcut that opens an m3u url directly, passes it to Safari, and starts playing!

- Copy the mp3 URL that you want using the [link mentioned](http://steveseear.org/high-quality-bbc-radio-streams/).

  > BBC Radio 1
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_one.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 1Xtra
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_1xtra.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 2
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_two.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 3
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_three.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 4
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_fourfm.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 4LW
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_fourlw.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 4 Extra
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_four_extra.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 5 Live
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_five_live.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 5 Live Sports Extra
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_radio_five_live_sports_extra.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Radio 6 Music
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_6music.m3u8
  >
  > BBC Asian Network
  >   http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/media/live/manifesto/audio/simulcast/hls/uk/sbr_high/ak/bbc_asian_network.m3u8
- Open the Shortcuts app in iOS 12
- Create a new shortcut
- Add a URL action

  [image: new shortcut]
- Paste the URL into the space below the action
- Add 'Open URLs" action

  [image]
- Tap the little settings icon in the top right, then tap Add to Siri

  [image: add to Siri]
- Record a Siri command, e.g. "Radio 4"

  [image: speaking]
- Tap Done

Comment: Could you put how to do it in the answer. An answer should be understandable when the link is broken. It is acceptable onl;y to provide a summary

Comment: Please add screen shots

Comment: This doesn’t work when the device is locked. Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Siri will play podcasts, and BBC publishes The Archers as a podcast. So you can ask Siri to “play the latest episode of The Archers” without any programming